# Quotation mark in lisp code macro output

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

How can i get something like:

```
(my-macro name) => (foo "foo-transformed-arg-name")
```

I only obtained

```
(foo \#" foo-transformed-arg-name \#")
```

How can i avoid the #" in my macro output?

Comment: what did you do? Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defmacro foo (sym)
  (symbol-name sym))
```

or

```
(defmacro foo (sym)
  (string-downcase (symbol-name sym)))
```

I don't get why you would need any macro like this, but you will know best.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want to do:

```lisp
(defmacro static-string (func &rest characters)
  `(,func ,(coerce characters 'string)))
```

Perhaps it may make sense if you need to define some string constants instead of creating them at run time...

And this is the only way I can think of you being able to arrive at your current result:

```lisp
(defmacro quote-symbol-quote (func symbol)
  (list func #\" symbol #\"))
```

Stackoverflow highlighting is misleading. What you are getting in the result is a function called with three arguments: the quote character, the symbol `foo-transformed-arg-name` and the quote character again.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution was very simple. My real probem was how can I convert mi argument symbol of a macro to an string.

```
(my-macro foo) => (other-func "foo")
```

That is convert the sybol foo to "FOO".
For that i used the **symbol-name** function